# Spring Data Couchbase problems with indexes

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm playing with couchbase and spring data couchbase. For that purposes I have installed couchbase with version `5.5.1 build 3511` and enabled test buckets. I've created user `beer-sample` with password `beer-sample` and added him all privileges to bucket `beer-sample`.

Then I've created [this sample application](https://github.com/bilak-poc/couchbase-poc) with configuration for couchbase. When I start the application and [query](https://github.com/bilak-poc/couchbase-poc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/bilakpoc/couchbasepoc/BeerSampleApplication.java#L22) for existing beers in bucket I'm getting exception:

```
com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException: View beer/all does not exist.
    at com.couchbase.client.java.view.ViewQueryResponseMapper$BuildViewResult.call(ViewQueryResponseMapper.java:211)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.view.ViewQueryResponseMapper$BuildViewResult.call(ViewQueryResponseMapper.java:185)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:113)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:281)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:118)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:73)
    ... 16 more
```

I guess that indexes should be automatically created with my config, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a view. Views are an old technology that is on its way out for most purposes. Use N1QL instead. N1QL requires at least a primary index for most queries to work at all, and specialized indexes for most queries to perform well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using Spring's couchbase repository interface in your `BeerRepository`. The `findAll()` method of the interface expects a Couchbase `View` to be present to get the data. So you need to either create the View manually in couchbase, or can annotate your `BeerRepository` interface with `@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "beer", viewName = "all")`, which would create the view automatically if it isn't present.

The mistake that you had done was to annotate your `Beer` class with `@ViewIndexed`, since the annotation is supposed to be used for your Repository interfaces. More info on the annotation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/query/ViewIndexed.html).

All that said, you should also check out leveraging Couchbase's `N1QL` queries for accessing data from Couchbase. You may use the `@Query` annotation on your repository methods for the same. More info on using the `@Query` annotation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.querying).

Comment: Thanks, it resolved my issue when I moved index annotations to repository. However I cant query for that data, because spring is using it's fqn of java class. I didn't found method how to tell the spring how to map value of type/_class.

Comment: @bilak sorry I didn't get what you said. Do you mean that you are not able to retrieve data with findAll() ? Could you please elaborate so that I can help if possible.

Comment: No, I just want to change the `_class` filed to `type`. This I know how to do with overriding `typeKey()` method. But how to change the value in this field from let's say `com.gitub.bilak.beersample.persistence.couchbase.model.Beer` to just `beer` is not clear to me. Maybe [this PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/pull/170) soves this issue.

Comment: Great buddy @MadhuBhat

Comment: Thank you @PradeepKrKaushal :)